# How I can filter items in UR template by custom params?

Tags: predictionio

Question is for [UR template](http://templates.prediction.io/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation)

When I have items stored like this:

```js
{
    "event" : "$set",
    "entityType" : "item",
    "entityId" : "ipad",
    "properties" : {
        "category": ["123", "1145"]
        "expireDate": "2016-10-05T21:02:49.228Z",
        "type" : "article",
        "group" : "sport",
    },
    "eventTime" : "2015-10-05T21:02:49.228Z" 
}
```

How can I filter only predictions, which have `type="article"` and `group="sport"`?

This query does not work:

```js
{
  “user”: “xyz”,
  “fields”: [
    {
      “name”: “type”
      “values”: [“article”],
      “bias”: -1 // filter out all except ‘article’
    },{
      “name”: “group”,
      “values”: [“sport”]
      “bias”: -1 // filter out all except ‘sport’
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you made import data to port 7070 (e.g.) > `pio build`   > `pio train` >  `pio deploy`? What error are you getting? And how is engine.json?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm also having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Updating pio to 0.9.5 and and UR to 0.2.2 resolved this problem for me.